# Deactivate the change of color when the user hovers over the header section of a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the shinydashoboard below in which I have made some adaptations in the sidebar and header. I was wondering if it is possible to deactivate the feature that makes the color of the header 'bolder' when the user hovers over it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style = "margin-left:-15px;margin-bottom:-83px;margin-top:-15px;padding: 0px 1190px 0px 0px ; width: 290px;",
        img(src = 'download.png', height = "125px",width="232px")),
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 58px ;color: black;font-family:Times-New Roman;font-weight: bold; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle))
    
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar" # id important for updateTabItems
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
        /* logo */
        .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                              background-color: #faf0e6;
                              }

        /* logo when hovered */
        .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {
                              background-color: #faf0e6;
                              }

        /* navbar (rest of the header) */
        .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                              background-color: #faf0e6;
                              }        

        
                              
        /* body */
                                .content-wrapper, .right-side {
                                background-color: #faf0e6;
                                }                     
                              '))),
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .navbar:hover {background-color:#faf0e6 ;}"))
      
      
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    
    
  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can control that with the following:

```
tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .navbar:hover {background-color: orange;}"))
```

Comment: Thanks but is there not a way to totally deactivate the change of color upon hovering?In my edited example I may use your method with the same colours but it looks like its getting grey upon hovering.

Comment: Sorry, I have not figured out that one. My suggestion would be to choose the same color or none.